# parsing xml with python, selecting a tag using a sibling tag as selector

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

from the following xml structure and using ElementTree i'm trying to parse the descriptions' text *solely* for the items where titles' text contain a certain keyword of interest. thanks for any suggestion

```
<data>
  <item>
      <title>contains KEYWORD of interest </title>
      <description> description text of interest "1"</description>
  </item>
  <item>
      <title>title text </title>
      <description> description text not of interest</description>
  </item>
  .
  .
  .
  <item>
      <title>also contains KEYWORD of interest </title>
      <description> description text of interest "k" </description>
  </item>
</data>
```

desired outcome:

description text of interest "1"

description text of interest "k"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) which support [XPath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html):

```
xml = '''<data>
  <item>
      <title>contains KEYWORD of interest </title>
      <description> description text of interest "1"</description>
  </item>
  <item>
      <title>title text </title>
      <description> description text not of interest</description>
  </item>
  .
  .
  .
  <item>
      <title>also contains KEYWORD of interest </title>
      <description> description text of interest "k" </description>
  </item>
</data>
'''

import lxml.etree
root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
root.xpath('.//title[contains(text(), "KEYWORD")]/'
           'following-sibling::description/text()')
# => [' description text of interest "1"', ' description text of interest "k" ']
```

Using [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET                                             
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
[item.find('description').text for item in root.iter('item')
 if'KEYWORD' in item.find('title').text]
# => [' description text of interest "1"', ' description text of interest "k" ']
```

Comment: thanks @falsetru, it solved the problem. also, for learning purposes, any suggestion along the ElementTree path?

Comment: @Marius, With ElementTree, you need more steps as far as I know: Find `title` nodes, filter them by their text, find sibling `description` nodes and retrieves their texts.

Comment: @Marius, I added `ElementTree` version. Check it out.

Comment: thanks again @falsetru for the ElementTree based solution too.